# Eloquent - Having problems using eager loading on nested relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to eager load nested relationships, but I'm having trouble returning the correct results.

Here are the models:

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function universities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\StudentApp\Models\UserUniversity');
    }
}
```

**UserUniversity.php**

```
class UserUniversity extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'user_id', 'university_id', 'choice' ];

    public function university()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\StudentApp\Models\University');
    }
}
```

**University.php**

```
class University extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'university';
}
```

What I want to do is get a user by ID, fetch the users universities from the `UserUniversity` pivot table, and then fetch the name of that university from the `University` table.

I've tried the following to test if it works:

```
$user = User::with('universities')->find($this->jwtObject->uid);
return $response->withJson($user->universities[0]->university);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'university.user_university_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `university` where `university`.`user_university_id` = 10 and `university`.`user_university_id` is not null limit 1) [] {"uid":"28c5a97"}
```

`user.user_university_id` is incorrect. That column doesn't exist and I'm not sure why it's trying to use that column.

What it should be using is `user.university_id`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add foreign key and primary key in relation:

```
public function universities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\StudentApp\Models\University', 'university_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) syntax is:

```
User::with('universities.university')
```

Also, make sure you've using the correct foreign key in the `university` table:

```
user_university_id
```

Or define another key in the relationship:

```
public function university()
{
    return $this->hasOne('\StudentApp\Models\University', 'another_foreign_key');
}
```